# How do I add and manipulate the values inside my pie chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using http://d3pie.org/ to generate a pie chart for my web application. Now, I want to manipulate the value appearing on my chart. Currently, the values appearing have more than 4 decimals. For example, 10.35234234234 . I just want 10.3523 to appear.

Here's my current code:

```
function drawPie(id,from,to,C,formula){
    var subArray = getSubArray(C.table,from,to);
    if(Object.keys(subArray).length){
        var partials = createPartials(subArray, C.attributes);
        //console.log("partials -> ",partials);

        formula = formula.slice(1,-1);
        //console.log("formula ->" , formula);
        formula = formula.split(",");
        //console.log("formula ->" , formula);
        var cloneFormula = formula.slice(); 

        for( var i in partials){
            if(i.substr(0,1) == "$"){
                for(var j = 0; j< formula.length; j++){
                    formula[j] = replaceFunction(i,formula[j],partials[i]);
                }

            }

        }

        //console.log("replaced formula ->" , formula);

        var data = [];

        var isEmpty = true;
        for(var j = 0; j< formula.length; j++){
            var label = cloneFormula[j].split(/(?=[-+*\/])/)[0].split(".")[1];
            var temp = {};
            try{
                temp.value = eval(formula[j]);
            }catch(err){
                temp.value = 0;
            }
            temp.label = partials[label + ".name"];
            temp.color = partials[label + ".color"];
            data.push(temp);
            if(temp.value != 0){
                isEmpty = false;
            }
        }

        if(isEmpty){
            return true;
        }

        //console.log("data ->" , data);

        var pie = new d3pie(id, {
            "size": {
                "canvasHeight": 400,
                "canvasWidth": 800, //see defect 1418
                "pieOuterRadius": "88%"
            },
            "data": {
                "content": data
            },
            "labels": {
                "outer": {
                    "pieDistance": 100
                },
                "inner": {
                    "format": "value"
                },
                "mainLabel": {
                    "font": "verdana"
                },
                "percentage": {
                    "color": "#e1e1e1",
                    "font": "verdana",
                    "decimalPlaces": 0
                },
                "value": {
                    "color": "#e1e1e1",
                    "font": "verdana"
                },
                "lines": {
                    "enabled": true,
                    "color": "#cccccc"
                },
                "truncation": {
                    "enabled": true
                }
            },
            "effects": {
                "pullOutSegmentOnClick": {
                    "effect": "linear",
                    "speed": 400,
                    "size": 8
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Can you help me try to modify the texts appearing inside my pie chart?

Comment: look for "labels.formatter" usage on http://d3pie.org/#docs

Answer (score 0):

use the following to strip the number and then round it.

```
function strip(number) {
    return (parseFloat(number).toPrecision(4));
}
```

example

```js
var number = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679

function strip(number) {
    return (parseFloat(number).toPrecision(6));
}

window.alert(strip(number));
```

For the generator you are using, go to the labels section, and under the label styles / Settings you will find the option for decimal places for percentage values. Enter the number of decimal places you would like to limit the labels to.

Comment: Which part of the code should I ask that? Sorry, still learning javascript :|

Comment: I have added it to my answer above, I hope that helps in this case.